# jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js breaking <nav> ID Selector

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am building a web page that uses the  tag to navigate the page -

```
<a href="#mymenutag">Menu</a>
...
<nav id="mymenutag">
<ul>
 <li class="first"><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
 <li><a href="happy.html">Happy</a></li>
 <li class="last"><a href="nowhere.html">Nowhere</a></li>
</ul>
/nav>
```

This generally works fine, except when I also include the script reference-

```
<script src="libs/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, the navigation no longer functions.  There are a number of other jquery mobile scripts being loaded as well, but this is the one that breaks the navigation.  There are some other ID Selectors that still work, but I think they are processed through jquery mobile.  This one is not; it just navigates to a new location on the same page.

I set up a working example on github which can be found here:

https://github.com/hypnoboy/jqmobile_breaks_html5_navt

The behavior can be observed by clicking through the pages. As a bonus and to make it easier to see, I added a jpg photo of my favorite "WTF" software installation moment.

Here is a complete sample web page in which the problem can occur:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <head>
        <!--begin entries for jquerymobile-->        
        <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        

        <!--end entries for jquerymobile-->
   </head>

    <body>
        <!-- start of navigation -->
         <a href="#mymenutag">Menu</a>
         <!-- end of navigation -->
           <script src="libs/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <!--    causes href navigation in the page to fail -->

            <header><div class=main_heading>
                <h1>Sad Test App (jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js is running)</h1></div>
            </header>

   <p>This is some sample text
    </p>
                    <a href="#mymenutag">Menu</a>
             <a href="#mymenutag" data-role="button" data-transition="slide">Menu</a>
     <img   id="front"   src="WP_000241.jpg"/>
           <!--start of navigation-->   
     <nav id="mymenutag">
    <ul>
     <li class="first"><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
      <li><a href="happy.html">Happy</a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="nowhere.html">Nowhere</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
             <!-- /end of navigation -->  



        <script src="js/vendor/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/helper.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="pages.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of JQuery Mobile traits is loading 2 pages at once into the DOM and showing just one. It is part of the JQM ajax functionality. If you have used an ID in a master page or part that is loaded into more than 1 of your pages you will probably find that upon inspecting your source at runtime you have duplicate IDs

Turning off the ajax functionality and having it do postbacks is a workaround, or use classes

Image showing the issue (image from pluralsight course video)

[image: Image showing the issue]

Comment: I don't think that is my issue - the problem happens on a page that is presented as a single page and I don't any sign of duplicate IDs.